# How to pass url encoded body parameters in logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a service call in which it takes URL encoded key values in body. I'm able to get response for my request in postman. But in logic app I want to call my end service with URL encoded body params. Somehow I'm not able to achieve this. Can someone help how to pass URL encoded params in body using logic app.

Clientid and grant-type I want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved by using concat with encodeuricomponent